# Amazon s3 Download process stops after 50% of downloading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, drupal-6, ubercart

I have a website that sales files.
After purchasing the product they gets unique link to the file from Amazon s3 that allows theme to download the file for limited times.

Lately my customers complain that the download process stops after 50% of downloading.

Because the file is downloaded directly from Amazon s3, I do believe that the problem is with the Amazon s3 service. But I cannot find any problem or change that have done by me that can cause this problem...

Did someone here dealt with this problem before?

Comment: "unique link" -- are you using signed URLs?  How much time do you allow before they expire?  Also, do you have logging turned on for the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's servers was offline... I use some services which are host their sites on Amazon servers and today they twice have had offline some time.